# How to add Legacy pre-made ESLint configs to Angular 15 project - Angular 15 to 16

Tags: angular, eslint, angular15, angular16

I'm in the process of upgrading my app to version 16 from version 15, I encountered some linting errors, turns out some plugins are removed from `angular-eslint` 16 onward and the remedy is to add those removed one manually to get you going.

The migration article says the following (link is [here](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/v16.0.0/docs/MIGRATING_FROM_TSLINT.md#legacy-premade-eslint-configs)):

> If you would like to recreate the ng-cli-compat and
> ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on configs as they exists in v15 and
> earlier, then you can use the following:

My question is how you actually do it? how to use the files author has suggested? How to add them to my Angular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the [migration on the angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/50345/files) a few months ago :

In the eslint config file (eg `.eslintrc.json`):

1. Add the different plugins :

```
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "@angular-eslint",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc",
    "eslint-plugin-import",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow"
  ],
```

2. then add all the rules :

```
  "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "off",
    "sort-keys": "off",
    "@angular-eslint/component-class-suffix": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
      "error",
      {
        "type": "element",
        "prefix": "app",
        "style": "kebab-case"
      }
    ],
    "@angular-eslint/contextual-lifecycle": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/directive-class-suffix": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
      "error",
      {
        "type": "attribute",
        "prefix": "app",
        "style": "camelCase"
      }
    ],
    "@angular-eslint/no-conflicting-lifecycle": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/no-host-metadata-property": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/no-input-rename": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/no-inputs-metadata-property": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/no-output-native": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/no-output-on-prefix": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/no-output-rename": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/no-outputs-metadata-property": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/use-lifecycle-interface": "error",
    "@angular-eslint/use-pipe-transform-interface": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/array-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "types": {
          "Object": {
            "message": "Avoid using the `Object` type. Did you mean `object`?"
          },
          "Function": {
            "message": "Avoid using the `Function` type. Prefer a specific function type, like `() => void`."
          },
          "Boolean": {
            "message": "Avoid using the `Boolean` type. Did you mean `boolean`?"
          },
          "Number": {
            "message": "Avoid using the `Number` type. Did you mean `number`?"
          },
          "String": {
            "message": "Avoid using the `String` type. Did you mean `string`?"
          },
          "Symbol": {
            "message": "Avoid using the `Symbol` type. Did you mean `symbol`?"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreParameters": true
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-new": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-parameter-properties": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-namespace-keyword": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": [
      "error",
      {
        "path": "always",
        "types": "prefer-import",
        "lib": "always"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/unified-signatures": "error",
    "complexity": "off",
    "constructor-super": "error",
    "eqeqeq": ["error", "smart"],
    "guard-for-in": "error",
    "id-blacklist": [
      "error",
      "any",
      "Number",
      "number",
      "String",
      "string",
      "Boolean",
      "boolean",
      "Undefined",
      "undefined"
    ],
    "id-match": "error",
    "import/no-deprecated": "warn",
    "jsdoc/newline-after-description": "error",
    "jsdoc/no-types": "error",
    "max-classes-per-file": "off",
    "no-bitwise": "error",
    "no-caller": "error",
    "no-cond-assign": "error",
    "no-console": [
      "error",
      {
        "allow": [
          "log",
          "warn",
          "dir",
          "timeLog",
          "assert",
          "clear",
          "count",
          "countReset",
          "group",
          "groupEnd",
          "table",
          "dirxml",
          "error",
          "groupCollapsed",
          "Console",
          "profile",
          "profileEnd",
          "timeStamp",
          "context"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-debugger": "error",
    "no-empty": "off",
    "no-eval": "error",
    "no-fallthrough": "error",
    "no-invalid-this": "off",
    "no-new-wrappers": "error",
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "name": "rxjs/Rx",
        "message": "Please import directly from 'rxjs' instead"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": [
      "error",
      {
        "hoist": "all"
      }
    ],
    "no-throw-literal": "error",
    "no-undef-init": "error",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "error",
    "no-unsafe-finally": "error",
    "no-unused-labels": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "object-shorthand": "error",
    "one-var": ["error", "never"],
    "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": "error",
    "prefer-const": "error",
    "radix": "error",
    "use-isnan": "error",
    "valid-typeof": "off"
```

Have a look here for [the list](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/245317c7bd83a94000e704060186098cadcf0195/docs/MIGRATING_FROM_TSLINT.md#legacy-premade-eslint-configs).